# Circles overlapping after transition with D3.pack

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have a JSON file which I reorganize using the d3.nest() function, which then is used to transition to a different state.

However, when I do the transition, the  circles in the top hierarchies overlap any which way, and their movement isn't very elegant (they appear and disappear our of nowehere). I managed to keep the top nodes on top by using a moveToFront() function, as was recommended on another question. This works great for the top nodes, but it doesn't work for every layer. I made the circles semi-transparent so it's easier to see what's going on.

I'm also trying to add labels but it completely messes up, no matter what I seem to do. I'm thinking maybe because the order is messed up?

Here is my code for the function in question. I also put three JSON file samples representing the three hierarchies I'm using.

If anybody can help, it would be greatly appreciated!

```
function update(i, duration) {
    var delay = 0;

    var root = changehierarchy(childdata, i);
    var focus = root;
    var nodes = pack.nodes(root);
    var v = [root.x, root.y, root.r * 2 + margin];
    var k = diameter / v[2]; view = v;


    var vis = svg.selectAll('circle')
    .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.name; });


        //.sort(function (a, b) { return a.depth < b.depth ? -1 : 1; })
        // update 
        vis.data(nodes)
          .transition()
          .each("start", function(d){ d3.select(this).moveToFront(); })
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("class", function(d) { return d.parent ? d.children ? "node" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root"; })
          .attr('transform', function(d) { return "translate(" + (d.x - v[0]) * k + "," + (d.y - v[1]) * k + ")"; })
          .style("fill", function(d) { return d.children ? color(d.depth) : d.color; })
          .style("opacity", function(d) { return d.children ? 0.4 : 1; } )
          .attr('r', function(d) { return d.r; });

        //enter
        vis.data(nodes)
            .enter()
            .append('circle')
            .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + (d.x - v[0]) * k + "," + (d.y - v[1]) * k + ")"; })
            .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r * k; })
            .attr("class", function(d) { return d.parent ? d.children ? "node" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root"; })
            .style("fill", function(d) { return d.children ? color(d.depth) : d.color; })
            .style("opacity", function(d) { return d.children ? 0.4 : 1; } );

        //exit    
        vis.exit()
          .transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .style('opacity', 0)
          .remove();

      var node = svg.selectAll("circle,text");

      d3.select("body")
          .style("background", color(-1));

      d3.selection.prototype.moveToFront = function() {
            return this.each(function(){
                this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
            });

      d3.selection.prototype.appendText = function() {
           var text = svg.selectAll("text")
                .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.name; });
                text.enter().append("text")
                  .attr("class", "label")
                  .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.parent === root ? 1 : 0; })
                  .style("display", function(d) { return d.parent === root ? "inline" : "none"; })
                  .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
      };
};
```

JSON Files :
First hierarchy

```
{
   "name":"POPULATION (n=8)",
   "children":[
      {
         "name":1,
         "name1":"Total",
         "name2":"POPULATION (n=8)",
         "eventA":"Event A is true",
         "eventB":"Event B is true",
         "color":"#944dff",
         "size":50
      },
      {
         "name":2,
         "name1":"Total",
         "name2":"POPULATION (n=8)",
         "eventA":"Event A is true",
         "eventB":"Event B is true",
         "color":"#944dff",
         "size":49
      },
      {
         "name":3,
         "name1":"Total",
         "name2":"POPULATION (n=8)",
         "eventA":"Event A is true",
         "eventB":"Event B is false",
         "color":"#944dff",
         "size":48
      },
      {
         "name":4,
         "name1":"Total",
         "name2":"POPULATION (n=8)",
         "eventA":"Event A is true",
         "eventB":"Event B is false",
         "color":"#944dff",
         "size":47
      },
      {
         "name":5,
         "name1":"Total",
         "name2":"POPULATION (n=8)",
         "eventA":"Event A is false",
         "eventB":"Event B is true",
         "color":"#FFFFFF",
         "size":46
      },
      {
         "name":6,
         "name1":"Total",
         "name2":"POPULATION (n=8)",
         "eventA":"Event A is false",
         "eventB":"Event B is true",
         "color":"#FFFFFF",
         "size":45
      },
      {
         "name":7,
         "name1":"Total",
         "name2":"POPULATION (n=8)",
         "eventA":"Event A is false",
         "eventB":"Event B is false",
         "color":"#FFFFFF",
         "size":44
      },
      {
         "name":8,
         "name1":"Total",
         "name2":"POPULATION (n=8)",
         "eventA":"Event A is false",
         "eventB":"Event B is false",
         "color":"#FFFFFF",
         "size":43
      }
   ]
}
```

Second hierarchy

```
{
   "name":"POPULATION (n=8)",
   "children":[
      {
         "name":"Event A is true",
         "children":[
            {
               "name":1,
               "name1":"Total",
               "name2":"POPULATION (n=8)",
               "eventA":"Event A is true",
               "eventB":"Event B is true",
               "color":"#944dff",
               "size":50
            },
            {
               "name":2,
               "name1":"Total",
               "name2":"POPULATION (n=8)",
               "eventA":"Event A is true",
               "eventB":"Event B is true",
               "color":"#944dff",
               "size":49
            },
            {
               "name":3,
               "name1":"Total",
               "name2":"POPULATION (n=8)",
               "eventA":"Event A is true",
               "eventB":"Event B is false",
               "color":"#944dff",
               "size":48
            },
            {
               "name":4,
               "name1":"Total",
               "name2":"POPULATION (n=8)",
               "eventA":"Event A is true",
               "eventB":"Event B is false",
               "color":"#944dff",
               "size":47
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"Event A is false",
         "children":[
            {
               "name":5,
               "name1":"Total",
               "name2":"POPULATION (n=8)",
               "eventA":"Event A is false",
               "eventB":"Event B is true",
               "color":"#FFFFFF",
               "size":46
            },
            {
               "name":6,
               "name1":"Total",
               "name2":"POPULATION (n=8)",
               "eventA":"Event A is false",
               "eventB":"Event B is true",
               "color":"#FFFFFF",
               "size":45
            },
            {
               "name":7,
               "name1":"Total",
               "name2":"POPULATION (n=8)",
               "eventA":"Event A is false",
               "eventB":"Event B is false",
               "color":"#FFFFFF",
               "size":44
            },
            {
               "name":8,
               "name1":"Total",
               "name2":"POPULATION (n=8)",
               "eventA":"Event A is false",
               "eventB":"Event B is false",
               "color":"#FFFFFF",
               "size":43
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Third hierarchy

```
{
   "name":"POPULATION (n=8)",
   "children":[
      {
         "name":"Event B is true",
         "children":[
            {
               "name":"Event A is true",
               "children":[
                  {
                     "name":1,
                     "name1":"Total",
                     "name2":"POPULATION (n=8)",
                     "eventA":"Event A is true",
                     "eventB":"Event B is true",
                     "color":"#944dff",
                     "size":50
                  },
                  {
                     "name":2,
                     "name1":"Total",
                     "name2":"POPULATION (n=8)",
                     "eventA":"Event A is true",
                     "eventB":"Event B is true",
                     "color":"#944dff",
                     "size":49
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "name":"Event A is false",
               "children":[
                  {
                     "name":5,
                     "name1":"Total",
                     "name2":"POPULATION (n=8)",
                     "eventA":"Event A is false",
                     "eventB":"Event B is true",
                     "color":"#FFFFFF",
                     "size":46
                  },
                  {
                     "name":6,
                     "name1":"Total",
                     "name2":"POPULATION (n=8)",
                     "eventA":"Event A is false",
                     "eventB":"Event B is true",
                     "color":"#FFFFFF",
                     "size":45
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"Event B is false",
         "children":[
            {
               "name":"Event A is true",
               "children":[
                  {
                     "name":3,
                     "name1":"Total",
                     "name2":"POPULATION (n=8)",
                     "eventA":"Event A is true",
                     "eventB":"Event B is false",
                     "color":"#944dff",
                     "size":48
                  },
                  {
                     "name":4,
                     "name1":"Total",
                     "name2":"POPULATION (n=8)",
                     "eventA":"Event A is true",
                     "eventB":"Event B is false",
                     "color":"#944dff",
                     "size":47
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "name":"Event A is false",
               "children":[
                  {
                     "name":7,
                     "name1":"Total",
                     "name2":"POPULATION (n=8)",
                     "eventA":"Event A is false",
                     "eventB":"Event B is false",
                     "color":"#FFFFFF",
                     "size":44
                  },
                  {
                     "name":8,
                     "name1":"Total",
                     "name2":"POPULATION (n=8)",
                     "eventA":"Event A is false",
                     "eventB":"Event B is false",
                     "color":"#FFFFFF",
                     "size":43
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you're incorectly using `vis.data(...)` by calling it 3 times for a single update. Only the first `data()` call is necessary, and it's also one place where you, correctly provided the 2nd argument, i.e. `function(d) { return d.name; }`.

(I've never tested this, but there's a chance that things would work ok if you added added that 2nd argument to the two other `data()` calls, but that would be inappropriate as well)

I replaced the two calls to `data()` with the appropriate thing. I also swapped the positions (ie the sequential order) of the enter and update blocks.

There's a chance the entering transition still wouldn't be quite right after this, but start from this:

```
var vis = svg.selectAll('circle')
  .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.name; });

// enter (it's not necessary to assign to 'var visEnter', but it's 
// available if you need to work more with that selection)
var visEnter = vis.enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + (d.x - v[0]) * k + "," + (d.y - v[1]) * k + ")"; })
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r * k; })
    .attr("class", function(d) { return d.parent ? d.children ? "node" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root"; })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return d.children ? color(d.depth) : d.color; })
    .style("opacity", function(d) { return d.children ? 0.4 : 1; } );

// update
vis
  .transition()
  .each("start", function(d){ d3.select(this).moveToFront(); })
  .duration(duration)
  .attr("class", function(d) { return d.parent ? d.children ? "node" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root"; })
  .attr('transform', function(d) { return "translate(" + (d.x - v[0]) * k + "," + (d.y - v[1]) * k + ")"; })
  .style("fill", function(d) { return d.children ? color(d.depth) : d.color; })
  .style("opacity", function(d) { return d.children ? 0.4 : 1; } )
  .attr('r', function(d) { return d.r; });


//exit    
vis.exit()
  .transition()
  .duration(duration)
  .style('opacity', 0)
  .remove();
```